# RestSharp and resilient http requests

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, httpclient, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to make API calls. What I have learnt for HttpClient is that it can lead to socket exhaustion when too many instances are created: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests
The RestClient class also accepts an HttpClient parameter, so I guess it's using HttpClient internally.

I'm not sure how RestSharp handles HttpClient instances internally, but should I instantiate the RestClient with a HttpClient created by the IHttpClientFactory implementation?

```
new RestClient(httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the `HttpClient` instance like that, it won't be disposed. The intention is that you might have a pre-configured `HttpClient` instance used as a singleton. It's not a good idea to dispose an external dependency by default, so RestSharp doesn't do it.

Besides, the issue with socket exhaustion is not caused by `HttpClient` being instantiated for each request but by the underlying `HttpMessageHandler`.

If you want to use the `IHttpClientFactory` internal instance caching (it doesn't cache the client, it caches the `HttpMessageHandler` instances), you can do it like this:

```
using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
using var restClient = new RestClient(httpClient);
```

You can also tell RestSharp to dispose the `HttpClient` instance:

```
using var restClient = new RestClient(httpClientFactory.CreateClient(), true);
```

and the factory will take care of caching the message handler.

The next major version of RestSharp will hopefully make it a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So would you say it makes sense to even use the HttpClientFactory with RestSharp?

Comment: Yeah, it totally does it if you want to avoid the problem described in the docs. Keep in mind that many properties of `RestClientOptions` are used to configure `HttpMessageHandler`, and when you provide your own `HttpClient` instance, those options won't work. I am working on making it explicit now, it will be better in v109.

Comment: and you really need to wrap the client instance in `using` and tell RestSharp to dispose the `HttpClient` instance it gets from the factory (my second code snippet).